# Adding up polygon areas involved in a single area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

I have a polygon shapefile comprised of 4 polygons representing landslides (see image). None of them are overlapped.
Number 1 comprises everyone (2, 3 and 4). Number 4 comprises number 3. Finally number 2 and 3 are indivual.

I've calculated the area of every individual polygon but I need to calculate the involved areas as mentioned above.
Is there any possibility of adding up the areas creating a new field using the field calculator?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new field to the layer, called A_combined

In the attribute table, select the target feature, enter an expression into the field update bar, and click "update selected."

[image]

Substitute the name of your layer into the following expressions:

For feature 1 (feature1 + feature2 + feature3 + feature4), use this expression

```
attribute( $currentfeature,  'A (km2)' ) 
+ attribute( get_feature( 'layer name', 'id',2), 'A (km2)' ) 
+ attribute( get_feature( 'layer name', 'id',3), 'A (km2)' ) 
+ attribute( get_feature( 'layer name', 'id',4), 'A (km2)' )
```

For feature 4 (feature3 + feature4), use this expression

```
attribute( $currentfeature, 'A (km2)' ) 
 + attribute( get_feature( 'layer name', 'id',3), 'A (km2)' )
```

For features 2 and 3, use this expression

```
attribute( $currentfeature, 'A (km2)' )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast answer. It worked! Awesome!